# WAMP install acts different than live install when uploading images

Tags: images, uploads

I have a WAMP installation of my live site running on Windows 7 using the WordPress WAMP [stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/installer) from Bitnami.  When I try to upload an image file to the WAMP installation, it does not work.  I can see that the image is processed and placed in the uploads folder, but it does not become active.  The only way I can get it to work is by explicitly filling in the pathname for the image in the theme options page, as shown below:

[image]

I have tried it using Firefox and Chrome, and the outcome is identical.

While I understand that I don't need to "upload" images since I am on the same machine and can simply do a copy to the uploads folder, using the "Upload Image" interface is necessary to generate versions of the image at various resolutions.

How can I get the WAMP stack to behave identical to a live site, and how can I go about debugging such a problem?

I am running WP 4.4.2 for both the WAMP install and the live site.

Comment: Does uploading images to posts work? If so then you should ask support from the theme author. I would also look for JS errors.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Thanks, will check other image uploads.  How do you go about debugging JS - I know, vast topic. :)

Comment: just impossible to guess what the problem might be. diving into the code of the theme and debuging each step is probably the only way

Comment: @MarkKaplun Post image upload works fine, so I would think this is a bug on a specific page that is manifested only on a WAMP install.

Comment: You might find some info in the Apache log.  There are so many components to the stack that it could one of thousands of possible problems.  Simply having an outdated version of imagick could cause the issue, for example.

Comment: @jdm2112 I see, too many layers.  I appreciate your input.